# quartz.net handling 1 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to doing load balancing with job services .I set the job and trigger detail to my local database with adojobstore.When I create the job, added to database and starting to job,its running correctly.Butwhen I try to connect to the database and run the job it does not work correctly .

I take these 2 errors

1. error retrieving job
2. handling 1 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time

So what can I do for this errors

Here is my quartz.config

```
# You can configure your scheduler in either <quartz> configuration section
# or in quartz properties file
# Configuration section has precedence

quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
quartz.threadPool.type = Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz

# this section configures the scheduler to use sqlite as the jobstore
# to use the RAM store just comment all of this out
# to use the sqlite store, uncomment all of this 
quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz 

quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default 

quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_ 

quartz.jobStore.clustered = true

quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SimpleSemaphore, Quartz 

quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, 
Quartz 

quartz.dataSource.default.provider = SqlServer-20

quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true

quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL = SELECT * FROM {0} LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = @ lockName

quartz.dataSource.default.connectionStringName = QuartzStore

quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString = Data Source=suleyman_pc;Initial Catalog=QuartzDeneme;Integrated Security=SSPI;

#quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer = true

# this section configures the scheduler to use sql server ce as the jobstore

#quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz 

#quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default 

#quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString = Data Source=quartz.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;

#quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_ 

#quartz.jobStore.clustered = true

#quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz 

#quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz 

#quartz.dataSource.default.provider = SqlServerCe-351

#quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
```

And Here is the My Program.cs for the strating the job.!!

```
ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        sched.Shutdown(true);
```

What can i do for this errors
Thank you for your answers...

Comment: _When I create the job, added to database and starting to job,its running correctly.Butwhen I try to connect to the database and run the job it does not work correctly_ What does that mean? Please clarify your question.

Comment: it's mean that,ı can run with adojobstore.And store the job,rtrigger to my localdb.But when ı creat other project and want to run this job from localdb.It cant running.

Comment: If i understand you right, then you need to make sure that have the same class names and **namespaces** for the jobs, otherwise Quartz won't find the classes. Take a look in the table `qrtz_job_details`, in the field `job_class_name` needs to be the same Fullname like in your solution.